# ERROR! simple program to Change BG Colors with button click using DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Here's my JS code. Console is showing

> randomColor is not defined

```
var colors = ["#81ecec", "#0984e3", "#fab1a0", "#81ecec", "#0984e3", "#fab1a0"];

let button = document.querySelector("#button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
   var changeColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
});

let content = document.querySelector("#container").style.background = changeColor;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Did you edit your code to have "changeColor" instead of "randomColor", because now you have an error that doesn't match your code.

Comment: I simply, shifted the Last Line of the Code (style.background) inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`changeColor` is only inside the click function readable because of the scope, so you had to change the color as well there. 
Even if you would declare it globally this wouldn't help you: There wouldn't be than be though any errors but the background color change would be executed only once at script start but than changeColor is null and so anything would happen.

```js
var colors = ["#81ecec", "#0984e3", "#fab1a0", "#81ecec", "#0984e3", "#fab1a0"];
let button = document.querySelector("#button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() { 
    let changeColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]; 
    let content = document.querySelector("#container").style.background = changeColor;
});
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <button id='button'>btn</button>
</div>
```